# Wrapper class for displaying multidimensional object

Tags: apex

I am trying to display a set 2D list of objects in a table on to a VF page.  I tried using a wrapper class since the list of objects are not custom or standard salesforce objects.

My controller is

```
public class MainReportController {

public List<sObject> reportList {get;set;}
public List<List<sObject>> finalReportList {get;set;}

// wrapper class

  public List<ReportTable> report { get; set; }
  public class ReportTable {
    public String Day { get; set; }
    public Date eventDate { get; set; }
    public String Venue{ get; set; }
    public String Show{ get; set; }
    public Integer Capacity{ get; set; }
    public Integer Sold {get; set;}
    public Integer Comp {get; set;}
    public Integer Issued {get; set;}
    public String Percent {get; set;}
    public Decimal Value {get; set;}
    public Integer Ems {get; set;}
    public Decimal Ems_Value {get; set;}
    public Integer Lock {get; set;}
    public Integer Available{get; set;}

    public reportTable(String day,Date dates,String venue,String show,Integer capacity,Integer sold,Integer comp,Integer issued,String percent,Decimal value,Integer ems,Decimal ems_Value,Integer lock,Integer available) {
      Day=day;
      eventDate =dates;
      Venue=venue;
      Show=show;
      Capacity=capacity;
      Sold=sold;
      Comp=comp;
      Issued=issued;
      Percent=percent;
      Value=value;
      Ems=ems;
      Ems_Value=ems_Value;
      Lock=lock;
      Available=available;
     }
  }
public void fetchReports()
{


/// some computation for variables below


  report = new List<ReportTable>();
  report.add(new ReportTable(day,null,'loc1',listStrings2.get(j),capacity,sold,comp,issued,percent,34.4,3,45.4,0,3));  
}}
```

VF PAGE

From Date :
To Date:

```
    <apex:column value="{!row.Day}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!row.eventDate}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!row.Venue}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!row.Show}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!row.Capacity}"/
    <apex:column value="{!row.Sold }"/>
     <apex:column value="{!row.Comp}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!row.Issued}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!row.Percent}"/>

  </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

This is not rendering on to the VF page

Comment: Did you check that you are getting value in your class variable?

Comment: The values are available in the class variable but not displaying in the VF page

Comment: hey do you want to use sobject in page level ? is that will solve your issue?

Comment: Check if you are rerendering this PBT.?

Comment: How can i check this?

Comment: Can you just add constructor and call your method `public MainReportController (){fetchReports();}`

Comment: Yeah I know Just wanted show you. If  initially works then after any button click or whatever action you make in vf page it should display the values. I can't see You are using rerender property. Can you pls add your action function code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot all!!!! I was not rendering the PBT .

Comment: cool  no problem  @gsanthan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner and outer class variables are using same name.

It should be something like this:

```
public reportTable (  String  dayOuter ,
                      Date    datesOuter ,
                      String  venueOuter ,
                      String  showOuter ,
                      Integer capacityOuter ,
                      Integer soldOuter ,
                      Integer compOuter ,
                      Integer issuedOuter ,
                      String  percentOuter ,
                      Decimal valueOuter ,
                      Integer emsOuter ,
                      Decimal ems_ValueOuter ,
                      Integer lockOuter ,
                      Integer availableOuter ) {
  Day           = dayOuter;
  eventDate     = datesOuter;
  Venue         = venueOuter;
  Show          = showOuter;
  Capacity      = capacityOuter;
  Sold          = soldOuter;
  Comp          = compOuter;
  Issued        = issuedOuter;
  Percent       = percentOuter;
  Value         = valueOuter;
  Ems           = emsOuter;
  Ems_Value     = ems_ValueOuter;
  Lock          = lockOuter;
  Available     = availableOuter;
 }
```

Or as crop mentioned,

```
public reportTable (  String  day ,
                      Date    dates ,
                      String  venue ,
                      String  show ,
                      Integer capacity ,
                      Integer sold ,
                      Integer comp ,
                      Integer issued ,
                      String  percent ,
                      Decimal value ,
                      Integer ems ,
                      Decimal ems_Value ,
                      Integer lock ,
                      Integer available ) {
  this.Day          = day;
  this.eventDate    = dates;
  this.Venue        = venue;
  this.Show         = show;
  this.Capacity     = capacity;
  this.Sold         = sold;
  this.Comp         = comp;
  this.Issued       = issued;
  this.Percent      = percent;
  this.Value        = value;
  this.Ems          = ems;
  this.Ems_Value    = ems_Value;
  this.Lock         = lock;
  this.Available    = available;
 }
```

Comment: oh God yes . I have changed it,Now the values are available but not populating on to the VF page

Comment: I am not sure, but after you run fetchReports() a new `report` variable value is probably not returned back to VF page. You might need to add `rerender` parameter to to your actionFunction.

Comment: why would the constructor argument names have to be different than the inner class member variable names? I do this all the time. For clarity, I would code the assignment statements as `this.day = day;` but that is just for clarity. Maybe there is something I don't know

Comment: Good point, @crop1645